# springboot jpa combine two tables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to query data from two tables,

location field in Translation is a foreign key from id field of Location

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Translation")
@Data
public class Translation {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @NotNull private String language;

  @NotNull private String name;

  @NotNull private String description;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "location", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  private Location location;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Location")
@Data
public class Location {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @NotNull private String code;

  @NotNull private String type;

  private Double longitude;
  private Double latitude;

  @Column(name = "parent_id")
  private Integer parentId;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = Translation.class, mappedBy="id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Translation> translations;
}
```

————————————————————————————————————————

But when I use a query

```
  @Query(
      "SELECT new com.afkl.travel.exercise.model.RetrieveLocationResponse("
          + "loc.code, tran.name, loc.type, loc.latitude, loc.longitude, tran.description, loc.parentId)"
          + "FROM Location loc LEFT JOIN loc.translation tran")
  List<RetrieveLocationResponse> fetchLeftJoin();
```

All the fields related to Translation is null, having no idea what happened

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

The following ones work for me.

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<Translation> translations;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "location")
  private Location location;
```

Comment: one location can have many translations right? So in this case is it possible that one location record has fetched many translations record? If that is the case how will this work?

Comment: I notice some probably mistakes on the mapping (as you described, `name = "location"` could be `name = "id"`). Enable the `show-sql` and show us the SQL query generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "location", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<Translation> translations;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "location")
  private Location location;
```